# Passing default parameter value (whatever it is)

Tags: c#

```
//method with an optional parameter
public void DoSomething(int a, int b = 42);

//caller
DoSomething(a, b: default);
```

Can this be done in C#?

You might say, "if you don't want to set the parameter, just call the method without it". But then I get ugly IFs like this in my code:

```
//kinda ugly :(
if(parameterIsSet)
    DoSomething(a, myValue);
else
    DoSomething(a);
```

When I could do this instead:

```
DoSomething(a, b: parameterIsSet ? myValue : default);
```

I can of course do this:

```
DoSomething(a, b: parameterIsSet ? myValue : 42);
```

**But I don't want to hardcode "42" in two places**

Comment: Do you've acces to the DoSomething definition and have rights to modifiy it?

Comment: Your logic seems to link `parameterIsSet` and `myValue`. Why not handle this logic inside `DoSomething`? i.e. `DoSomething(a, myValue)` even if `myValue` is `null`

Comment: @rbm maybe he hasn't access to DoSomething code.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no shortcut for this, but you could reflect the method to get the default parameter value [as explained in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759887/how-invoke-method-for-a-method-by-default-value-for-parameters-by-reflection). My approach would be to set the default value to a specific (invalid) value like null, -1, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, Size.Empty, String.Empty or whatever applies and fill in the actual value in the method.

Comment: You can create a code like this:
MyClass.DoSomething(a, b: parameterIsSet ? myValue : MyClass.GetDefault());

Comment: But that would mean writing `GetDefault()` method

Comment: That would also mean that a class can have only one "default".  Whereas even a single method may have more than one.

Comment: Found something else: If you invoke the method via reflection, you can pass [Type.Missing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.type.missing(v=vs.110).aspx) in the parameter array to use the default value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a case like this, I would usually use `null` as mentionned in a comment. Thus the code would look like this:

```
public void DoSomething(int a, int? bOverwrite = null)
{
    int b = bOverwrite ?? 42;
    // remaining code as before...
}
```

In such case, you would generally remove `parameterIsSet` variable and initialize a variable with null and set a value if necessary:

```
int? myB = null;
if (/* some condition */)
{
    myB = 29;
}

DoSomething(a, myB);
```

If you still have `parameterIsSet`, you could call the function like this:

```
DoSomething(a, parameterIsSet ? b : default(int?));
```

**Other alternatives:**

If you have many such parameters, it might be simpler to create a class for parameters and set its default in constructor:

```
class DoSomethingParameters
{
    public DoSomethingParameters() { A = 12; B = 42; }
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}

var parameters = new DoSomethingParameters();
parameters.A = /* something */;

if (/* some condition */ {
    parameters.B = 29;
}

DoSomething(parameters);
```

And if some cases, the ugly IFs might be the best solution as many times, you might use the same condition to initialize `b` anyway or you need more variables to keep track of everything and the final code might be even uglier than the ugly code.

```
if (/* some condition */)
{
    int b = some_complet_expression;
    DoSomething(a, b);

    // Some other stuff here....
}
else
{
    DoSomething(a);

    // Different stuff here...
}
```

In particular, if you would have other code that depend on the condition after the call, it might be the base solution. Each case is specific. With experience, you learn how to write best code for the situation.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the `null` is the way to go, like in your 1st code snippet. Thanks