# MSTest - Default value for a parameter within a DataTestMethod

Tags: c#, mstest

I am trying to use a default value for a parameter in a DataTestMethod. I have the following code:

```
[DataTestMethod]            
[DataRow("sampleString", true)]
[DataRow("sampleString2")]            
public async Task SampleTest(string parameterA, bool parameterB = false)
{
    var condition = await AsyncOperation();

    Assert.AreEqual(parameterB, condition);
}
```

However, I get: `System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.`

Is there a way to define a default value for a method parameter and skip stating it in the DataRow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest approach would be writing your own DataRowAttribute. If you take a look at this answer, about checking default parameters in a method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20759946/7225096, then you could write something like this:

```
public class MyDataRowAttribute : DataRowAttribute, ITestDataSource
{
    public MyDataRowAttribute(object data1) : base(data1)
    { }

    public MyDataRowAttribute(object data1, params object[] moreData) : base(data1, moreData)
    { }

    public new IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
        object[] args = new object[parameters.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < base.Data.Length)
            {
                args[i] = base.Data[i];
            }
            else if (parameters[i].HasDefaultValue)
            {
                args[i] = parameters[i].DefaultValue;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Not enough arguments provided");
            }
        }

        return new List<object[]> { args };
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[MyDataRow("sampleString", true)]
[MyDataRow("sampleString2")]
public async Task SampleTest(string parameterA, bool parameterB = false)
{
    var condition = await AsyncOperation();

    Assert.AreEqual(parameterB, condition);
}
```

Comment: I really thought I am missing something or doing it wrong. It is really strange such a simple functionality is not already in place working. Thank you.